# C# - Creating a saveable object

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I want to create a class library, that contains an interface that objects can derive of, lets say `ISaveableObject`.

Now, this interface should implement the following functionality:

- Objects that derive off this interface should have a method `ToSaveableObject` (similar to the `System.Object.ToString()` method).
- And it should contain a specific constructor, which takes an array of objects as its parameter.

The connection between these two should be that the `ToSaveableObject` method returns a string that takes all the properties that are needed for the `object[]` and convert it into a readable string and return it.

Am I going in the correct direction by wanting to use an interface or is an abstract class better suited for this case?

Sadly, interfaces cannot implement constructors, so is there another way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: use an abstract base class that inherits from your intended interface. What you want is more of an implementation detail which is more than what an interface can provide.

Comment: interfacet no "should implement" but maybe "should plan contract"

Comment: I dont understand "should have specific constructor". World of "saveable" or "serializable" solutions never require "specific constructor", many want at least protected no args ctor. With code discussion will be better

Comment: So now there is a `ToString` and a `ToSaveableObject` which both returns a string that describes the object they are called on. Is it excessive?

Comment: ToString has always sense "human friendly" and result cannot be used in reverse way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an abstract base class to form your contract for derived classes. What you want is more of an implementation detail which is more than what an interface can provide.

abstract base class could look like this

```
public abstract class SaveableObject {
    protected object[] parameters = new object[0];

    protected SaveableObjectBase(object[] objects) {
        this.parameters = objects;
    }

    public abstract string ToSaveableObject();
}
```

So now derived classes have to implement the `ToSaveableObject()` method and will have access to the objects passed in the constructor to generate the string.

If the construction algorithm for the `ToSaveableObject` method is the same for all derived types then you should just implement that method in the base abstract class so that all derived classes will have the functionality already built in.

Comment: Your answer (for me) is a sign, that both half of solution are independent. Probably i will write similar code, but is result of bad design decisions

Comment: I really like this solution. Only one question: Can you also put the `parameters` field in the interface?

Comment: @IanH. fields are protected, so can be accessed in derrives classes. You can think about 'readonly' to initialise once and only once (first assigment is wrong)

Comment: No, interface ... is interface. I repeat: seems bad design. Functionality of "being salveable' should not depend on fields

Comment: @JacekCz Why not? The `parameters` field doesn't have to be implemented in the final object and it is good for the `ToSaveableObject()` function. As far as I can say, this fully answers and solves my question.

Comment: @IanH. WAS implemented because derived from Base class, (maybe, You say: not needed) . So I said wrong design

Comment: @JacekCz Can you suggest a better one?

Comment: I actually think the `ISaveableObject` interface should be skipped entirely. I think it's a case over over-implementation. Can you think of a situation where `ISaveableObject` is implemented to a class, but not via `SaveableObjectBase`? Wouldn't that be against your implementation pattern? Why not simply have a abstract class called `SaveableObject`?

Comment: The base class can be seen as an implementation detail while the interface can be used for abstractions (ISP). `SavableObject` would  have been a good name as well. It is more of a naming issue which would be open to different opinions. I called it that just out of habit.

Comment: 1) What is the use of the private parameterless constructor? Remove it, it's doing nothing. 2) If the base abstract class is public then the interface seems unnecessary; you are already establishing a contract with the base class, what is the added value of an interface in this scenario? Your just duplicating contracts; if you decide to change or add to the contract defined by the interface you have to do the same in the base class and vice versa, so what is the point if everyone can or should already use the latter?

Comment: @diemaus an interface is desirable for objects referencing instances of SaveableObject

Comment: I am going to implement a general `ToSaveableObject()` function, so a virtual method may be better because it doesn't have to be overridden.

Comment: @Mick how would referencing an abstract class, instead - change this?

Comment: @IanH. I agree with the general function. making it virtual still allows derived classes the ability to override it if needed.

Comment: @diemaus references to an abstract class couple the code to a specific implementation, which fails SOLID principles 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design).  References to an interface are not tied to a specific implementation of that interface.

Comment: @Mick I fail to see that a abstract class is a "specific implementation". If the abstract class, IS the "base", then it's not an implementation, as nothing has been "implemented". But maybe `SaveableObject` should be an interface instead; but that's besides my point, which is, having `IFoo`, `FooBase` and `Foo` is overly verbose and causes ambiguity. It is my personal philosophy that Hungarian-notation interfaces and `*Base`-classes are just lazy implementations, and actually "something else" in disguise.

Comment: @diemaus well that's a matter of opinion. I don't agree.  Referencing a base class means that you can only replace the implementation with other implementations that inherit the base class and all functionality within the base.  As a rule, clearly referencing interfaces rather than classes will give you greater flexibility and the ability to replace an object with a completely different implementation and greater compliance with the Liskov substitution principle